# Aptana Studio 3 SHIFT+ENTER option select

Tags: aptana

In Aptana right now, when we do SHIFT+ENTER, it brings up two choices:

- New method - Press 1
- Insert new line after current line - Press 2

I want to default it to the second option, but I have not found any option for it. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

1. Under Commands find the Bundle that shows the key binding you want to change
2. Locate the name of the binding
3. Under Commands > #BINDING# > edit binding
4. The ruble project will appear in the Project Explorer
5. Under the command folder locate the command and update its binding in the .rb file
6. Restart Aptana